# Use jQuery to Create a Fixed <div> whose Position is Relative to a Centered <div>?

Tags: css

I think the title explains it all but this is what I'm trying to do:

I have a site that is center-aligned and I want to have a fixed  (or sliding, however you want to describe it) move down the page as a user scrolls. I am able to get this to work using jQuery when I define the 's position as absolute but obviously that creates it's position relative to the whole browser window. Relative to the content, it should be 980px to the right, but using Absolute it's somewhere in the middle of the page and does not stay in the same place on the page when the window is resized. Using position:relative puts the  in the right place but does not allow it to move when the page scrolls, it scrolls with the page.

Does that make sense? I see all sorts of examples using absolute positioning which would work great if my site was aligned to the left but it's not.

Ideas?

You can see my site as a work-in-progress here: http://cdn.twelvestops.com/wordpress_one. Feel free to poke in the code and whatnot. (and for the record, the theme designer isn't helping much.)

Note: I know that my site isn't centered using auto margins but as if it was all text using the .center class in the CSS.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We're here to help you, not to simply do the work for you... The best way to get a good, usable answer is to narrow down your question to something specific, and if possible, provide code and examples, showing what you have tried.

Comment: I figured it out.

My problem was two fold:

1) that I had my floating DIV outside the centered container DIV, not inside it

and

2) I modified the position using margin-left versus left. This way, I could treat the DIV as if it was truly aligned to the left of the container DIV but with 980px of a margin on the left side so it seemed like it was actually next to the container (instead of on top of it).

Posting here helped me work it through differently than I would have normally considered.

Thanks!

Comment: Great, well done. If you documented your question a little bit better, you could answer it with your solution and that would help future visitors to this site who have the same problem as you.